# Google Chrome missing extensions icons / reinstall extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, reinstall

My Chrome extension icons have gone missing as in the pic:

[image: Chrome extensions icon missing]

I've browsed the profile folder and the .png files are missing.

A quick way to fix this would be to force Chrome to reinstall the extensions.

Is this possible / how?

Any other suggestions that don't involve removing the profile all together?

Comment: Try clicking Developer mode on the right side while on the page `chrome://extensions` and then click update extensions now and see if they reappear.

Comment: Already tried this. Did not do anything as far as I can see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but this fixed the issue:

1. Turned off sync of extensions
2. Deleted every extension
3. Turned on sync of extensions
4. Chrome automatically installed extensions - Problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm for me when my browser just wasn't showing icons or space at all (not even the placeholders).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as signing in -- I was signed out from Google somehow. I had to do this for every Chrome user on my system.

1. Go to chrome://settings/
2. Click Sign In (the very first setting)
3. Log in on the dialog box that comes up

Then all your extensions will come pouring back in.